# fread fseek struct member only in C

Tags: c, struct, fread, fseek

In C I'm trying to select a specific member of a struct and print it out. I wonder, what is the suggested format for such an operation? I've tried nearly everything I can think of. I can't seem to limit it to the specific `chunk` member of the struct.

```
fseek(in, sizeof(d.contents.datas.chunk), SEEK_SET);
fread(&ch, 1, 1, in);
fprintf(out, "%02x", (int)(ch & 0x00FF));
```

It seems I can get either all of the struct data, or only one character. For some reason the data is also not coming out right, for instance `bytes` should be the actual `bytes`, but it's coming out as `1`. Clearly there is something really wrong with the way the data from this struct is being printed. Could it be to do with big endian vs little endian? I know the file I'm accessing is big endian.

The struct Im accessing is as follows:

```
struct chunkInfo
{
    int chunkInformation; 
    int bytes;

    union
    {
        struct
        {
            long size;     
            char chunk[1];     
        } datas;                 
    } contents;                  
};
```

Comment: #pragma pack (while ignoring endian)

Comment: Yes, if you are on an intel architecture and receive data in big endian, you need to convert it. Check out e.g. `hton` and `ntoh`.

Comment: Generally, it is probably safest to use an ascii format like json or xml for network data transmissions. What if the sending machine uses 64 bit ints but yours uses 32? Etc.

Comment: I would love to find out if what Im doing is a problem with big/little endian. I personally dont think it is, because the "chunk" member, is definitely binary and I should not need to worry about it's format (its format will be dealt with, by the software that reads this file). I just need to find a way to select a member of a struct, which sounds easy, but apparently is extremely difficult in C. I think I need to seek the file for the beginning byte that contains "chunk" (using fseek) and then fread that section. But still it eludes me. Im sure it's much easier than I am making it out to be.

Comment: Hi Dieter, #pragma pack, is that really needed to read a simple struct and select only that member for reading?

Comment: No, `#pragma pack` is not crucial to getting the code to work.  Choosing the correct offset to seek to is crucial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeking to the wrong place in the file. Assuming the endian of your machine is the same as the endian of the file, then this will work:

```
fseek(in, long(&d.content.data.chunk[0] - &d), SEEK_SET);
fread(&ch, 1, 1, in);
fprintf(out, "%02x", (int)(ch & 0x00FF));
```

The first line calculates the offset in bytes of chunk in the structure. You were using the sizeof(chunk) which of course just returns 1.

If the endian is different, then you will have to convert each non char character to the correct endian after reading in the structure.

Comment: And there's also `offsetof()` from `<stddef.h>` that can do the offset calculation.

Comment: I've been trying for around 1 week to resolve this problem, as im a bit new to C and both of you have resolved it for me. I take my hat off to you guys, thanks soooo much :)